# Yo angular generate error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower, yo

I install nodejs and npm on ubuntu 14.04, by source code.

```
root@wemet:~/ang# npm version
{ http_parser: '1.0',
node: '0.10.34',
v8: '3.14.5.9',
ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
uv: '0.10.30',
zlib: '1.2.8',
modules: '11',
openssl: '1.0.1j',
npm: '1.4.28' }
```

I installed yo and generate-angular as global This is my full package install of local:
https://gist.github.com/thinksource/ba33f0cad073f3d4dc46

When I want to do:

```
root@wemet:~/ang# yo angular

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '../../string/is-string'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/n
ode_m odules/inquirer/node_modules/cli-color/node_modules/es5-ext/array/from/shim
.js:9:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I do not know what is the is-string module. I check it at https://www.npmjs.com/ but can not find it.

When I run the bower cache clean:

```
root@wemet:~/ang# npm i make-iterator --save-dev
info trying registry request attempt 1 at 00:21:04
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/make-iterator
http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/make-iterator
info trying registry request attempt 1 at 00:21:04
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/for-own
http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/for-own
info trying registry request attempt 1 at 00:21:05
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/for-in
http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/for-in
make-iterator@0.1.1 node_modules/make-iterator
└── for-own@0.1.2 (for-in@0.1.3)
root@wemet:~/ang# bower cache clean

module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '../function/makeIterator_'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/
rray/collect.js:2:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I find the module make-iterator, but even if I install make-iterator and I still meet error when I run bower cache clean.

Comment: Oh I hate these npm errors, run `bower cache clean` and `npm cache clean` and try again. Sometimes it works :/

Comment: @Rigotti I added your recommandation, but still error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the problem, I need to upgrade my npm version from 1.4.28 to 2.1.2. 
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

answer of [@user504909](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504909/user504909) will solve the problem **But** Good Solution is Upgrade `Nodejs` version from `0.10.34` to `0.12.0` As the result of upgrading `Nodejs` version, `npm` version will upgrade too from `1.4.28` to `2.1.2`

To Upgrade `Nodejs` Version according to [nodesource Blog](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories) :

```
# Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

# Then install with:
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For Answer about upgrade `Nodejs` version with `Ubuntu` OS -> [See This Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js)